# Where are all our committed users?

Tags: discussion

Looking at our [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics) I notice that it says about 10% of the users who committed to the site proposal have actually signed up. This is a little worrying given that the private beta is <strike>almost</strike> now over. The equivalent number for all the other beta sites I checked was between 30% and 90%+. Anyone have an idea why our participation is so low? (I guess if you're reading this, you probably don't know the answer ;-p I just felt the need to rant)

For ideas about how to pull in more people, who didn't commit, see [How should we promote the site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-should-we-promote-the-site)

Comment: Yeah, this is disturbing low. There may be a bit of lag between that figure and the actual one, but it seems about right actually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the problems is the long time the site needed to reach beta. Look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/?page=13&tab=newest, where you can see that the Physics proposal is one of the oldest proposals, and of these only two (Physics together with [Homebrewing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619/homebrewing-beer-wine-etc)) are currently in a beta with < 10 days. All other older proposals are either already at the > 90 days mark or still rather far from reaching beta. Maybe this was too long to wait for some, or they will join in later. Let's hope things improve during the next 83 days...

Answer (score 2):

This is very strange:

> 234 users committed
>   10.3% signed up for beta
>   0% fulfilled commitment

Clearly we were more than 23 during the private beta ... and I don't know what they mean with "fulfilled commitment".

Comment: One fulfills a commitment when a SE site you committed to has left public beta.

Comment: OK, that explains that part.

Comment: @Nol: You need to post 10 questions or answers as well to fullfil.

Comment: @Kenny: Ah yes. And hopefully a lot more!